Tracking GEE API costs with workload tags: Unable to get complete EECU summary
I am using Python to make multiple GEE API calls and track costs by assigning workload tags using:
import ee  
ee.data.setDefaultWorkloadTag('sample_workload_tag')  

In the GEE Monitoring Console, I aggregate EECU-seconds by workload_tag, but the table often shows -, even though activity is visible on the graph for the same time range (see screenshots).
Issues:

EECU usage is not summarised for the workload_tag in the table, making it hard to predict charges.
The graph shows activity, but the table fails to display totals for some tags.

Questions:

Is there a better way to track EECU usage for individual scripts?
Why does the table show - despite visible activity in the graph?
Are there alternative methods to monitor GEE API costs accurately?




The cloud monitoring tools is terrible, but there's some pointers here: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/monitoring_usage#view_consumption_in_cloud_monitoring
The important part is the "grouping by workload tag", in section 5.
